# Save content of ArrayList to external storage

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a balance program where I used

```
ArrayList <Double> balance = new ArrayList();
```

I was wondering how I can I save the elements that I add to the list with

```
a  add(list);
```

So the next time I open the program the same elements will be there.

Comment: You have to store this data somewhere (database, file), and load it info your list before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Serialization mechanism for storing the object to file.

Declare your class implementing `Serializable` interface

```
class YourClass implements Serializable{
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void populateList(){
        list.add("xyz");
        list.add("abc");
    }
}
```

Serializing your list to a file use below code:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("arrayList.list");
ObjectOutputStream objOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
objOutputStream.writeObject(list);
objOutputStream.close();
```

Deserializing your list from file use below code:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("arrayList.list");
ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
List<String> list = (List<String>) objInputStream.readObject();
objInputStream.close();
```

Comment: Note that element in list must be serializable for this to work.